# Upgrade from Windows 7 to Win10, what happens?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

If I will accept the Windows 10 upgrade from Windows 7, will all my games and programs stop working? How does it work?

Do they just give you a link to download it and then you do the rest (one) or they somehow replace your Windows 7 with Windows 10 (two)?

If number one, then no problems.

If number two, then will that keep all your games and programs currently installed and will they all work ok?

Comment: Until systems start upgrading, you won't know. That said, the popup lets you *reserve* a copy, but you can do the upgrade later.

Comment: This question is about installed software and Win 10 compatibility.  The proposed duplicate is about retaining personal data.  It doesn't address this question.

Comment: The same thing that happened when upgrading from Vista to 7 or 7 to 8 or ...? Everything (except perhaps your AV scanner) will stay. It’s nothing special, really.

Comment: @fixer1234 - We cannot predict what software the author owns, will have compatibility problems, for obvious reasons.  As for this not being a duplicate "then will that keep all your games and programs currently installed?" is a question we can answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### If I accept the Windows 10 upgrade will all my games and programs stop working?

> **Will my devices and apps work with Windows 10?**
>
> Windows 10 is designed to be compatible with the vast majority of
>   Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 devices -- so your device is most likely
>   compatible.
>
> **For details on your specific device and apps, you can use the Get Windows 10 app to do a compatibility check. Click the menu in the
>   upper left of the app, and select “Check your PC” or “Your PC is good
>   to go.” This displays any compatibility issues we find and recommends
>   a resolution; while we don’t have info on every app or device in
>   existence, it provides a comprehensive list of all known potential
>   compatibility issues.**
>
> Some Windows 10 features will require advanced hardware and not all
>   features and services are available on every device, nor in every
>   market. For instance, Cortana is not available in all markets.

Source [Windows 10 Q&A](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq)